# Vaadin BrowserFrame not displaying HTTPS sources

Tags: vaadin7

I can't seem to get a Vaadin(7) BrowserFrame to open https sources, and am struggling to understand why that might be. With http:// sources the web page is opened just fine, but I just get a blank page when using a https://www.google.co.uk; tcpdump shows that the a request was served, but it's not displayed in the browser window.

```
class BrowserWindow extends Window {

  BrowserWindow(URI externalUri) {
    center()
    setClosable(false)
    setDraggable(false)
    setResizable(false)
    setSizeFull()
    setModal(true)

    def ex = new ExternalResource(externalUri.toString())
    BrowserFrame browser = new BrowserFrame("Browser", ex)
    browser.setSizeFull()

    content = browser
  }
}
```

It works just fine with

```
getUI().getCurrent().addWindow(new BrowserWindow("http://www.truespeed.com")
```

but not with

```
getUI().getCurrent().addWindow(new BrowserWindow("https://www.google.co.uk")
```

Does anyone know why that might be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is usually a problem caused by mixed (https and http) content. The BrowserWindow might be trying to load an http page / resource which is "Potentially Dangerous". If you open the browser console, you will be able to see the error because of which the content was not loaded.

In short: If a https parent window tried to load a resource over http which compromises the security of the entire page, the browser can/will not load that resource.

More detailed information about mixed content can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/what-is-mixed-content?hl=en)

Make sure that the resource you are trying to load uses https to get around that problem (if mixed content is the problem).