# Vaadin BrowserFrame not working

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I am simply trying to load Google web page using Vaadin's BrowserFrame component and it's not working.

I can load https://vaadin.com but not https://www.google.com. I have tried both BrowserFrame and Embedded APIs but no luck.It displays a blank white page.

```
Embedded e = new Embedded("Vaadin web site", new ExternalResource(
                "https://www.google.com"));
        e.setType(Embedded.TYPE_BROWSER);
        e.setWidth("100%");
        e.setHeight("100%");
        panel.setContent(e);
```

and

```
ExternalResource source = new ExternalResource("https://www.yahoo.com");
            contentBrowser = new BrowserFrame(caption, source);
            contentBrowser.setSizeFull();
            panel.setContent(contentBrowser);
```

If i use https://vaadin.com site loads fine.

Comment: Have a look in the browser console. I expect there's some kind of security exception.

Answer (score 3):

Some sites send the `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` header to prevent their content to be displayed in sites from a different domain. That's the case of google.com.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem is even worse
BrowserFrame randomly loads, sometimes (i get some messeage of we can't find the site).
We know this URL works, if i access it directly.
I just wanted my web app to open a Panel with a BrowserFrame and the help in there.
I might need to revert to opening a whole new browser page with the help URL.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36135226/vaadin-browserframe-not-displaying-https-sources

Comment: I think one reason is that the help URL is on https and if come in from a vaadin http session this fails. But it is not consistent. So extremely hard to figure out.